# How to unit-test an object that contain a type union using typescript, karma and sinon?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, mocha.js, sinon-chai

I'm doing unit-testing for a project which is written in typescript with angular framework, by applying karma with mocha and chai frameworks. And there's an interface for the object as:

```
interface ISolution {
    _id: string;
    paymentFrequency: PaymentFrequency;
};
```

And PaymentFrequency type is defined as:

```
type PaymentFrequency = 'MONTHLY' | 'ANNUAL' | 'SINGLE';
```

In the controller,

```
open(solution: ISolution) { };
```

The problem is when I tried to mock the solution as:

```
let solution = { _id: 'aa0', paymentFrequency: 'MONTHLY', ....};
let spy = sandbox.stub(controller, 'open').withArgs(solution);
```

Typescript gave me the error as "type string is not assignable to type paymentFrequency". Let me know if there's a way to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using following each type becomes a interface. Because instead of any this will strict the type checking.

[refer this for explanation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html)

**Example:**

```
interface ISolution {
    _id: string;
    paymentFrequency: monthly | annual | single
};

interface monthly{
    kind:"MONTHLY"
}
interface annual{
    kind:"ANNUAL"
}
interface single{
    kind:"SINGLE"
}


var fun=(obj:ISolution)=>{
 console.log("hererer",obj)
} 
var y:monthly={kind : "MONTHLY"}
var x= { _id: 'aa0', paymentFrequency:y}
fun(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to use it and it solved the problem. It took a while to get back to you because I don't have a right to change the interface design and so I tried to mock all the interfaces first and then tested it.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to disable type checks in tests with `<any>` type casting when needed, but it's not the case. In fact, typing system will detect a mistake here, `Monthly` isn't `MONTHLY` and certainly isn't compatible with `PaymentFrequency`.

```
let solution = { _id: 'aa0', paymentFrequency: 'MONTHLY', ....};
```

will result in inferred `solution` type, `{ _id: string, paymentFrequency: string }`. The information that `paymentFrequency` is actually `MONTHLY` is lost, `paymentFrequency` isn't compatible with and `PaymentFrequency`, and `solution` is no longer compatible with `ISolution`.

It should be:

```
let solution: ISolution = { _id: 'aa0', paymentFrequency: 'MONTHLY', ....};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, it was my typo error and it's already 'MONTHLY' not 'monthly' in the code and I've already corrected it in my question

Comment: I see. This was a good point about why exactly you shouldn't resort to <any> before you really should. I'd expect `let solution: ISolution` to work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again. I tried let solution: ISolution and it gave me undefined when I tried to pass it to the function and checked for the result.